# Angular Universal initial load deployed app has empty page source (nothing inside app-root) unlike localhost

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm currently working on deploying Angular Unviversal app via Azure Pipelines. The page is up and running. But I've come accross an issue while trying to set dynamic meta tags. I'm using Angular's Meta to implement those.

Everything works fine on the localhost. I build the app and start main.js. Then I view page source, everything looks good, the meta tags are there, app-root is filled with appropriate HTML and Angular components:
`<app-root ng-version="14.2.2" ng-server-context="other"><router-outlet></router-outlet><app-landing _nghost-sc182="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-sc182="" class="flex min-h-[100vh] w-full flex-col">...</app-root>`.

But when the app is deployed on Azure, page source is "empty".
Meta tags don't work, `<title>` inside `<head>` didn't update either and app-root has nothing in it and looks like this:
`<app-root ng-version="14.2.2" ng-server-context="other"><router-outlet></router-outlet><!--container--></app-root>`
No HTML/Angular components inside it.

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Are you using @angular/pwa? Can you see app-root content after using ctrl+F5 when viewing the source? Does the page you visit send api-calls?

Comment: @Pieterjan no, I'm not using @angular/pwa. There is no content inside app-root after ctrl+F5. The pages that I need meta tags to work do not have any API calls. For now I set prerendering to those pages that need meta tags, which isn't the best because the navbar on the page shows user as signed out on the initial load. I will give @angular/pwa a look

Comment: Ah no, I was just asking for angular/pwa because in that case you'll always receive only the contents of **index.html**. All of your answers narrow down your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Azure build pipeline. Angular Universal and its server side rendering doesn't behave as it should if the build pipeline is set up as everyone is saying online. I've only seen people say you need to copy main.js from the server folder of the project. Well the SSR doesn't work at all in that scenario. I copied the whole server folder and SSR works normally after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run the app using npm run dev:ssr
after a lot of search I find [this](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1598)

**Shortly To solve this issue:**
You have to make `<app-root>` tag in index.html without attributes.